# Collision detection wont work in Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, collision-detection

So I'm making this project for school where we have to create a game and I picked space invaders. So it's going pretty well but the collision detection won't work. I've spent hours on google trying to find my problem but I couldn't. Here are the 2 JS files.

```
var newPlayer=0;
var hero = new Object();
var playerCount=0;
var pTag="";
var redImage=$("#red");
var blueImage=$("#blue");
var greenImage=$("#green");
function Hero(n,life,speed,buls)
{   
    var that=this;
    playerCount++;
    this.name=n;
    this.lives=life;
    this.speed=speed;
    this.bulSpeed=buls;
    this.warning=lowLives;
    function stats()
    {   
        alert("Name: " + that.name + "\n" + "Lives: "+ that.lives + "\n" + "Speed: " + that.speed + "\n" + "Bullet speed: " + that.bulSpeed);
    }
    function lowLives(life)
    {
        if(life==1)
            alert("You have low lives. Be careful!");
        else
            alert("Don\'t worry! You still have " + life + " lives left");
    }
    this.buttonTag=$("#" + n + "B")
    this.buttonTag.dblclick(startTheGame);
    this.imageTag=$("#" + n);
    this.imageTag.click(stats);
}
function newPlayerCreation1()
{
    hero=new Hero("Red",3,5,6);
    $("#RedB").off('click');
}
function newPlayerCreation2(){
    hero=new Hero("Blue",4,3,4);
    $("#BlueB").off('click');
}
function newPlayerCreation3(){
    hero=new Hero("Green",2,8,2);
    $("#GreenB").off('click');
}

$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#RedB").click(newPlayerCreation1);
    $("#BlueB").click(newPlayerCreation2);
    $("#GreenB").click(newPlayerCreation3);
});
```

And this is the code where all the action happens

```
var position;
var position1;
var bulletCount=0;
var enemy=new Array(20);
var enemyVerticalCenter;
var enemyHorizontalCenter;
var verticalDifference;
var horizontalDifference;
var bulVerticalCenter;
var bulHorizontalCenter;
function startTheGame()
{
    $("p").remove();
    $("button").remove();
    $("img").remove();
    document.title="Space invaders";
    var backGround = $("<div id='bground' style='background-color:black; width: 500px; height: 600px; position: relative; top: 0px; bottom: 0px; left: 0px; right: 0px; margin: auto; background-repeat:no-repeat; border:10px;'>");
    $("body").append(backGround);
    var player = $("<img id='player' src='" + hero.name + ".png' style='position: absolute; height:40px; width:40px; left: 250; top: 540;'>");
    var base1 = $("<img src='baseshelter.jpg' style='position: absolute; height:80px; width:60px; left:36; top: 440;'>");
    var base2 = $("<img src='baseshelter.jpg' style='position: absolute; height:80px; width:60px; left:153; top: 440;'>");
    var base3 = $("<img src='baseshelter.jpg' style='position: absolute; height:80px; width:60px; left:286; top: 440;'>");
    var base4 = $("<img src='baseshelter.jpg' style='position: absolute; height:80px; width:60px; left:413; top: 440;'>");

    for(i=1;i<=15;i++){
        if(i<=5)
            enemy[i]=$("<img src='space_invaders_alien.png' style='position: absolute; height:80px; width:60px; left:" + (i-1)*98 + "; top:0;'>");
        else if(i>5 && i<=10)
            enemy[i]=$("<img src='space_invaders_alien.png' style='position: absolute; height:80px; width:60px; left:" + i%5*98 + "; top:100;'>");
        else
            enemy[i]=$("<img src='space_invaders_alien.png' style='position: absolute; height:80px; width:60px; left:" + i%5*98 + "; top:200;'>");
    }
    $("#bground").append(base1);
    $("#bground").append(base2);
    $("#bground").append(base3);
    $("#bground").append(base4);
    $("#bground").append(player);
    for(i=1;i<=15;i++)
        $("#bground").append(enemy[i]);
    $("html").keyup(stop).keydown(moveAndFire);
    function enemyMoving()
    {
        for(var i=1;i<=15;i++)
        {
            enemy[i].animate({left: "+=50" + "px"}, 1000, "linear")
                    .animate({left: "-=50" + "px"},1000, "linear");
        } 

    }
    function stop(evt) 
    {
        player.stop(true);
    }

    function moveAndFire(evt)
    {
        if (player.position().left > 0 && evt.keyCode == 37) 
        {
            player.css("left", (player.position().left - hero.speed) + "px");
        } 
        else if (player.position().left < (backGround.width() - player.width()) && evt.keyCode == 39) 
        {
            player.css("left", (player.position().left + hero.speed) + "px");
        }
        else if (evt.keyCode==32)
        {
            bulletCount++;
            position=player.position();
            var bullet=$("<img id='bullet' src='bullet.png' style='position: absolute; height:30px; width:5px;'>");
            $("#bground").append(bullet);
            $("#bullet").css({ position: "absolute",top: player.position().top + "px", left: (player.position().left + 18) + "px"});
            bullet.animate({top: "-=540" + "px"},{
                                                    duration: 3000/hero.speed,
                                                    step: checkCollision(bullet,enemy),
                                                    done: bullet.remove()
                                                });
        } 
    }
    var interval=setInterval(enemyMoving,1000);
}
function checkCollision(bul,obs)
{
    for(i=1;i<=15;i++)
    {
        enemyVerticalCenter = obs[i].position().top + obs[i].height()/2;
        enemyHorizontalCenter=obs[i].position().left + obs[i].width()/2;

        verticalDifference = bul.height()/2 + obs[i].height()/2;
        horizontalDifference = bul.width()/2 + obs[i].width()/2;

        bulVerticalCenter = bul.position().top + bul.height()/2;
        bulHorizontalCenter = bul.position().left + bul.width()/2;
        if(Math.abs(bulVerticalCenter - enemyVerticalCenter) <= verticalDifference && Math.abs(bulHorizontalCenter - enemyHorizontalCenter) <= horizontalDifference)
        {
            $(bul).remove();
            $(obs[i]).remove();
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the html code

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Character creation</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p id="name">Choose your Character</p>
        <p class="info">Click the button once to create a hero, click the image of a hero to view its stats after creating him and double click the button to start the game with that hero</p>
        <p class="info">The hero you start the game with must be the last one you created</p>
        <img name="image" id="Red" src="Red.png" width="100px" height="100px">
        <img name="image2" id="Blue" src="Blue.png" width="100px" height="100px">
        <img name="image3" id="Green" src="Green.png" width="100px" height="100px">
        <br>
        <button id="RedB" style = "position: absolute; left:12px; top:213px">Choose Red!</button>
        <button id="BlueB" style = "position: absolute; left:112px; top:213px">Choose Blue!</button>
        <button id="GreenB" style = "position: absolute; left:212px; top:213px">Choose Green!</button>
        <script src="jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="startGame.js"></script>
        <script src="script.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

So my bullet won't even be created. When I remove the `done: bullet.remove()` in the second jquery file, it won't collide with the enemies. Can someone tell me why?

Comment: Press F12 and check the console for errors.

Comment: I've done it, not a single error

Comment: Can you make a jsFiddle? (or provide an url where the code runs as we  can easily browser-debug wherever it is)